# PYTHON - Através de um input, exibindo a soma, a média o maior e o menor valor dos números inputados

Tags: python, loop, input, while

Eai pessoal, eu tenho o seguinte exercício que ele me da uma alguns inputs de números das quais eu preciso apresentar a soma, a média, o menor e o maior valor dos inputs.

o meu input é algo como

```
10  # **AONDE A PRIMEIRA LINHA INFORMA A QUANTIDADE DE NÚMEROS DO INPUT**
40
90
20
200
19
99
507
2021
300
701
```

Até o momento eu fiz esse código com uma estrutura de repetição while

```
num = int(input())         #inputa os num
sum = 0 #inputa a soma
for x in range(num):       #para cada input dentro do range de input ele repete o abaixo
    sum += int(input())    #soma os inputs na variavel sum
    media = sum/num
print(sum)                 #printa soma
print ("%.2f" % media)     #printa a media
```

e bem as duas funções de exibir a soma e a média funcionam bem, **mas como faço para exibir o menor e o maior valor que passou por esse input?**

No caso, o resultado para o input que mostrei acima deveria ser

```
soma = 3997
media = 399.70
menor = 19 
maior = 2021
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

É recomendável que você crie uma variável para cada um dos resultados que deseja gerar, no caso: `maior` e `menor`.
As duas variáveis devem necessariamente receber o primeiro valor inserido pelo usuário, sendo assim:

```
numero = int(input('Insira um número:'))

maior = numero
menor = numero

contador = 0

while contador == 0:
   numero = int(input('Insira outro número:'))
   
   if numero > maior:
      maior = numero
   if numero < menor: 
      menor = numero
   
   repetiçao = str(input('Deseja continuar [S/N]?')).lower

   if repetiçao == 's':
      pass
   if repetição == 'n':
      contador = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo algumas observações:

- Na pergunta não foi utilizado o laço de iteração `while` e sim um laço
  de iteração `for`. Mais adiante será visto que o identificador `sum` é
  utilizado por uma função embutida e ao sobrescreve-lo perde-se a
  funcionalidade.
- Como parece ser uma a entrada automatizada e por motivos de brevidade
  irei dispensar mensagens ao usuário assim como a validação e tratamento de
  exceção para valores inseridos.

#### Seguindo o raciocínio da pergunta...

Uma alternativa usando o algoritmo da pergunta seria declarar mais duas variáveis para receber os valores do maior e do menor elemento da série.

As variáveis `soma`, `maior` e `menor` são inicializadas com primeiro elemento da série. Itera-se do próximo ao último elemento da série adicionando o elemento iterado a `soma` e o substituindo em `maior` e `menor` quando necessário.
Ao terminar a iteração tira-se a média e é imprimido o resultado.

```
n = int(input())                     #Obtem o número de entradas a serem lidas.

soma = maior = menor = int(input())  #Carregue soma e maior e menor com o primeiro elemento da serie.
#Do segundo ao último elemento da serie...
for _ in range(n-1):
    e = int(input())                 #...leia em e elemento.
    soma += e                        #...adicione em soma o valor de e.
    if e > maior: maior = e          #...se e é maior que maior então maior recebe e.
    if e < menor: menor = e          #...se e é menor que menor então menor recebe e.
    
media = soma/n                       #Calcula a média fora do loop.

#Imprime os valores calculados.
print(f"soma = {soma}\nmédia = {media:.2f}\nmenor = {menor}\nmaior = {maior}")
#soma = 3997
#média = 399.70
#menor = 19
#maior = 2021
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no https://ideone.com/G5OsvQ</sup>

O que é uma boa solução pois apresenta boa performance e do ponto de vista de consumo de memória é excelente, numa entrada de poucas linha parece indiferente mas numa entrada com milhões a bilhões de linhas o fato das entradas serem descartadas após processadas pode evitar uma quebra do sistema por falta de memória.

#### O uso de listas...

No caso de entradas menores onde seguramente a estruturação dos dados antes processamento não irá pressionar a memória é possível dispor de certos confortos que a linguagem oferece.

O interpretador do Python é distribuído contendo várias [funções](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html) e [tipos](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html)  embutidos que estão sempre disponíveis além da [biblioteca padrão](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/index.html) que fornece uma ampla gama de recursos.

Para o problema em específico algumas funções embutidas podem ser uteis:

- [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum): Soma os itens de um iterável da esquerda para a direita e retorna o total.
- [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#min): Devolve o menor item de um iterável ou o menor de dois ou mais argumentos.
- [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max): Devolve o maior item em um iterável ou o maior de dois ou mais argumentos.

Em especial para esse problema pode ser util o uso do tipo [list](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) que é uma [sequencia mutável](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

Com as informações acima problema pode ser dividido em etapas:

1. Ler a primeira linha para descobrir a quantidade de elementos a seem lidos.
2. Coletar as entradas
3. Calcular algumas das propriedades da série entrada.
4. Imprimir os resultados.

```
e = []                        #Declara a lista e onde serão acondicionados os valores entrados.
n = int(input())              #Obtem o número de elementos a serem lidos.

#Itere por n vezes...
for _ in range(contador):
  e.append(int(input()))      #...lê uma linha e adiciona a lista e.
  
#Efetua os respectivos cálculos.
soma = sum(e)
media = soma / n
menor = min(e)
maior = max(e)

#Imprime os valores calculados.
print(f"soma = {soma}\nmédia = {media:.2f}\nmenor = {menor}\nmaior = {maior}")
#soma = 3997
#média = 399.70
#menor = 19
#maior = 2021
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no https://ideone.com/hG4UWs</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Tem 2 maneiras

Na 1ª, definimos uma variável `maior` e `menor`, as quais vão ser definidas inicialmente como sendo o 1º valor digitado e depois serão atualizados caso atendam os requisitos de ser maior ou menor que os valores anteriores

```
#inputa o número de entradas
rep = int(input())

#inputa a 1ª entrada
num = int(input())   

#define o menor e maior valor
menor = num
maior = num
#inicializa a soma
soma = num 

for x in range(1, rep):     #Executa X-1 vezes, pois já executou uma vez fora do while
    num = int(input())
    soma += num    #soma os inputs na variavel sum
    
    if num < menor: menor = num     #Verifica se o número atual é menor que o menor número
    elif num > maior: maior = num   #Se não for o menor, verifica se o número atual é maior que o maior número
    
media = soma/rep
    
print()
print("Menor:", menor)
print("Maior:", maior)
print("Soma: ", soma)
print ("Media: %.2f" % media)
```

Na 2ª, criamos um array que armazena os valores da entrada e depois utilizamos as funções próprias do Python para descobrir os valores

```
valores = []
for x in range(int(input())):       #para cada input dentro do range de input ele solicita um novo valor
    num = int(input())
    valores.append(num)
   
print()
print("Menor:", min(valores)) #Função 'min' devolve o menor valor de uma lista
print("Maior:", max(valores)) #Função 'max' devolve o maior valor de uma lista
print("Soma: ", sum(valores)) #Função 'sum' devolve a soma dos valores da lista
print ("Media: %.2f" % (sum(valores)/len(valores)))
```

Não utilize nomes de funções como `sum` como nome de variáveis, pode até funcionar no momento, porém em um código maior isso pode ocasionar em resultados inesperados